# Offical Twitter iPhone App & Bit.Ly Pro

Tags: twitter, iphone, url-shortening

I have a bit.ly pro account with my own custom short domain setup.

Can anyone tell me how I can use my custom short domain as my custom URL shortner for the the Official Twitter App for iPhone?

I have tried putting:

`https://api.bit.ly/v3/shortner?login=USERNAME&apiKey=APIKEY`

but that doesn't seem to be correct.

It works fine with Seesmic Desktop but that uses a bit.ly plugin which simply asks for your username and API key.

Comment: I have the iPhone 4 but do not see API Keys at the bottom of the screen. Has this capability been removed ?

Comment: @Robert - In te Twitter app go to Settings > Services and then scroll down to the bottom. The API Keys option should be there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about settings for an iPhone app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it appears that I was being slightly stupid.  You don't need to enter a Custom URL Shortening at all.

You need to set the URL Shortening Service to `j.mp (bit.ly)`

Then scroll right down to the bottom of the screen and go to `API Keys` you can then set your Login & API Key in here.